# What is the origin of the idiom "get/be shot of"?

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrase-origin

#### Definition

> **Get/be shot of someone/something**
>
> *slang*
> To get rid of.
>
> — [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-shot-of)

#### Examples

- *He didn't want to be seen near me and couldn't wait to **get shot of** me.*
- *City experts still reckon the company wants to **get shot of** its brewing division.*
- *The house was full of bad memories and he was glad to **be shot of** it.*

Comment: It's either a mishearing or miscopying of the idiom _be/get shut of_, with that meaning. As in Kipling's "The 'eathen": _Gettin' clear o' dirtiness, gettin' done with mess, Gettin' shut o' doin' things rather-more-or-less_.

Comment: [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+shot+of) too.

Comment: When I was a kid in the 50s/60s the term was "get shit of" (though "shit" was often slurred into something like "shid").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED ("shoot" 37 b) says "get shot" is from a dialectal passive form of the verb "shoot", here meaning "to rid (of)". This (mostly obsolete) sense of "shoot" derives from the older meaning of "shoot", which originally meant "go swiftly and suddenly" (in an intransitive sense), with citations pre-1400 for things like lightning, arrows, and boiling pitch, but came to also mean to send swiftly.

"get"+verb was formerly a common way of forming the passive in some forms of English, found for instance in [early modern Scots](https://dsl.ac.uk/about-scots/history-of-scots/grammar/), and in more recent dialects. This makes "to get shot" the same as "to be shot", comparable to the expression "to be rid of something" (the passive of "to rid someone of something"). (This is distinct to the modern causative use of get.)

The oldest OED citation is comparatively recent, from the north of England where you might expect get-passives to be used:

> 1805   R. Anderson *Ballads in Cumberland Dialect* 39   "He'd gi'e aw his gear to get shot o' the gout."

However the OED also mentions a similar sense of shut, which dates back to around 1500 in Chester and slightly later Durham:

> 11. a. †To set (a person) free from, relieve of (something troublesome). Obsolete except in passive (dialect and colloquial) to be, get shut of, (dialect) shut on, to shut one's hands of: to be rid of, free from; also elliptical.

Related meanings of "shut" include to bar or separate from something else, so there may well be a connection.

Reference: "shoot, v.". OED Online. June 2022. Oxford University Press. (accessed June 17, 2022).

Answer (score 5):

Because "get shot of" and "get shut of" are so similar orthographically, phonetically, and in everyday meaning, my answer looks into the origins of both.

---

***Modern reference work coverage of 'get shot of' and 'get shut of'***

Entries for "get shot of" appear in three idiom dictionaries that I have on hand, and an entry for "get shut of" appears in one. From *Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms* (1998):

> **get shot of** sb/sth *British informal* to get rid of  someone or something | *She got shot of her no-good  husband and went back to university.* **be shot of** sb/sth | *This boy has caused so much trouble that the school just want to be shot of him.*

From *Longman Dictionary of English Idioms* (1979):

> **get shot of** *coll[oquial]* to settle or deal with (a job, difficulty, etc.) so that it needs no further attention: *I'll be home as soon as I can, but there's a small problem I'd like to get shot of  before I leave the office.*

And from John Ayto, *Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms*, third edition (2010):

> **get** (*or* **be**) **shot of** get (*or* be) rid of *British informal*
>
> ...
>
> **be** (*or* **get**) **shut of** be (*or* get) rid of *informal*

The entries in Ayto's dictionary strongly suggest that the meaning of the two phrases today is virtually identical. Was it ever thus?

---

***Early reference work coverage of 'get shut of'***

Although dictionaries as early as Elisha Coles, [*A Dictionary, English-Latin and Latin-English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SHVmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP332&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnr-STjrb4AhVOHTQIHdOBCf8Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1679) mention the phrase "get shut of," these dictionaries don't include English definitions of the English term.

The earliest Google Books matches for English dictionary definitions of "get shut of" are from the 1700s.

From Nathan Bailey, [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sM2uyrbP7CkC&pg=PT62&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-5pzzlrb4AhWxIjQIHeNgC_QQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1721):

> TO **GET SHUT of** a Thing, (of *Sceadan*, Sax. or *scheyden*, Teut. to separate or disjoin) to get rid of, or clear ones self from a Thing.

From Thomas Dyche & William Pardon, [*A New General English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=p2FgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP765&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn--vQm7b4AhUdAzQIHYfsB5E4HhDoAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1740):

> **SHUT** (V.) to stop up or close, or put to the door to prevent another from coming in. *To **get shut of***, to be free, clear, or rid of any person or thing.

From Samuel Johnson, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mf1cAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP673&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTptzMmrb4AhWlIzQIHQf5CLg4FBDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1755):

> **SHUT.** Participial adjective. Rid; clear; free. [Cited example:] We must not pray in one breath to find a thief, and in the next to **get *shut* of** him. *L'Estrange*.

None of these three dictionaries has a corresponding entry for "get shot of."

---

***Early reference work coverage of 'get shot of'***

The earliest reference works to mention "get shot of" are from the 1800s.

From Samuel Johnson & Henry Todd, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8kEm0xTaXS0C&pg=PP688&dq=%22get+shot+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ-tennrb4AhVJAzQIHT-UB6cQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shot%20of%22&f=false) (1818):

> **SHOT of.** *part.* Discharged; quit; freed from: a colloquial expression: as, he cannot get *shot of* it.

From John Brockett, [*A Glossary of North Country Words, in Use*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rxm7CtWO7D4C&pg=PA190&dq=%22get+shot+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ-tennrb4AhVJAzQIHT-UB6cQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shot%20of%22&f=false) (1825):

> **SHOT-OF**, freed from. *To get **shot of** a person*—to get rid of him.

It bears noting that Todd's revision retains Johnson's entry for *shut* as a participial adjective, with L'Estrange's quotation using the phrase "get shut of" included as an example.

And from Frederick Dinsdale, [*A Glossary of Provincial Words Used in Teesdale in the County of Durham*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3BFJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA116&dq=%22get+shot+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-qtmcqLb4AhVDRs0KHeGOC9E4ChDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shot%20of%22&f=false) (1849):

> **SHOT:** To get *shot of*, i. e. to get rid of.

---

***Early acknowledgments of 'get shot of' and 'get shut of' as variants***

Neither Brockett nor Dinsdale includes any mention of "get shut of," indicating that, in the places they were concerned with, only the wording "get shot of" was in use. And yet, during this same period, other compilers of British regional glossaries were including only the form "get shut of."

From Roger Wilbraham, [*An Attempt at a Glossary of Some Words Used in Cheshire*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fh9JAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA47&dq=%22a+glossary+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lCEjVPbWMIfHiwLovoHwCg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBjhQ#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false), second edition (1826):

> **TO GET SHUT OF A PERSON** is to get rid of him. See Diversions of Purley, in voce Shoot.

From William Carr, [*The Dialect of Craven: In the West-Riding of the County of York*](https://books.google.com/books?id=awo0jGdymGEC&pg=PA122&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjvv3Dw7b4AhWOHc0KHSutCHs4KBDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1828):

> **SHUT**, ... 2. To quit, to rid. BELG. schutter, to eject. "I cannot **get *shut* on** him."  *Mr. Todd* has admitted into *Johnson's Dict.* *shot* of the same signification, though differently pronounced, "To **get *shut* of** a business," se debarasser d'une affaire. *Miege*.

From Joseph Hunter, [*The Hallamshire Glossary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=87tY7YWWwhgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22Hallamshire+Glossary%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwmdiYuLb4AhVFAp0JHQ0HC6AQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22shut%20of%22&f=false) (1829):

> **SHUT**, quit. "He has **got shut of** an ill neighbour."

From Roger Forby, [*The Vocabulary of East Anglia*](https://books.google.com/books?id=rhULAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA130&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi72uiMubb4AhUQHzQIHVnZABs4FBDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false), volume 2 (1830):

> GET, *v.* 1. Phr. "To ***get shut* of**," to get rid or quit of. The exact meaning, no doubt is, to get parted or shut out from something disagreeable. BR shot.

"BR" refers to Brockett's *A Glossary of North Country Words*, which addresses only "get shot of." It thus seems that Forby views the two phrases as ways of spelling the same expression.

From Benjamin Smart, [*A New Critical Pronouncing Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DT8yAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA564&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjvv3Dw7b4AhWOHc0KHSutCHs4KBDoAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1836):

> *To* **SHOOT** ... *To be shot of*, to be discharged or cleared of.
>
> ...
>
> *To* **SHUT** ... *To be shut of*, or *get shut of*, is used by some old writers for *to be shot of*, which see under To Shoot.

From William Holloway, [*A General Dictionary of Provincialisms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=D19gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8r6jivLb4AhXSAjQIHTEnDYw4HhDoAXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1838):

> ***To* GET SHUT OF A PERSON**, is to get rid of him, to have no further dealings with him ; he being as it were shut out or excluded. *Norf[olk], East Sussex.*

From George Lewis, [*A Glossary of Provincial Words Used in Herefordshire and Some of the Adjoining Counties*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nCxKAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8r6jivLb4AhXSAjQIHTEnDYw4HhDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1839):

> *To* **GET SHUT OF**, to get rid of. This word is also used in Gloucestershire, as well as in Yorkshire and Cheshire : Craven Gloss., Hunter, and Wilbr. in v . · See Tooke, Div. of Purl., vol. ii. p. 130.

And from Anne Baker, [*Glossary of Northamptonshire Words and Phrases*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ofxIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA232&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis-rzVq7b4AhWlA50JHankADsQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1854):

> **SHUT.** Free from, rid of. "Good *shut* of bad rubbidge," is a common vulgar saying. Wilbraham suggests that it means "the door is shut upon him." See Diversions of Purley, in voce *shoot*. We have extended applications of this word, coalescing with the original import."I wish I could get *shut* of this cough." "It was a very dull market to day , I could not get *shut* of my goods."

The reference to "Diversions of Purley" in Wilbraham, echoed in Lewis and in Baker, is to John Tooke, [*The Diversions of Purley*](https://books.google.com/books?id=apUSnU9xawAC&pg=PA11&dq=%22Diversions+of+Purley%22+volume+2&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl0K_KwLb4AhVdKEQIHcL9BIIQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Shot%20Shotten%20Shut%22&f=false) (1805/1829), which presents *shot* and *shut* among a set of English words that Tooke says derive from a common root and retain a common meaning:

> All these, so variously written, pronounced and applied, have but one common meaning : ... *To Shite*, i. e. projicere, dejicere, to throw, to cast forth, to throw out.

Charles Richardson, [*On the Study of Language: An Exposition of The Diversions of Purley by John Horne Tooke*](https://books.google.com/books?id=s5o_AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA152&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8r6jivLb4AhXSAjQIHTEnDYw4HhDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1854) offers this brief discussion of *shut*:

> **SHUT,** pronounced by the common people *shet*, and anciently written also with the vowels *i* and *y*. To *shet* the door is merely to *throw* or *cast* the door to. To **get *shut* of** a thing means, to get a thing *thrown* off or *cast* from us.

The earliest U.S. reference work I've found that identify "get shot of" and "get shut of" as variant phrases is John Bartlett, [*Dictionary of Americanisms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9sVUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA302&dq=%22get+shot+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL9_mpqLb4AhX6GzQIHUM1AJk4FBDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shot%20of%22&f=false) (1848):

> **SHUT.** Quit, rid. *To be shut of*, or *to get shut of*, signifies to be or get rid of. We also say, to be or get *shot* of. The expression is common in England. [Cited example:] "Do you call those houzen—those things that have stoops to them?" as he saw here and there a log cabin or unpainted hut, such as abound in the sparsely settled regions of the South. "They pass for houses hereabouts," replied Mr. S——, "though the original owners have generally contrived to get ***shut* of** them and gone coon-hunting to the Mississippi."—*Letter in N.Y. Journal of Commerce.*

And from Alfred Elwyn, [*Glossary of Supposed Americanisms*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9_tIAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA100&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjos4n_tLb4AhWNO80KHUgaAus4ChDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1859):

> **SHOT OF**, for freed from. (Brockett.) The usual pronunciation is as spelt in the Hallamshire Glossary, *shut*. I never heard the word but in Chester County, Pennsylvania, and there it is common. The early settlers of that county were Quakers, and most of these, I believe, from the North of England. A widow, once importuned by a man whom she did not care much for, though her worldly substance was too considerable to be neglected by a prudent man, married him, as she said, to **get *shut of*** him. They also say, to **get *shut of*** a farm, or a horse. *Shot* is also the past participle of *shut*, or, as it is written in Chaucer, *shette*; did you *shette* the door? it was *shot*; who *shot* the door? This way of using *shot* and *shette*, for shut, is common in New England, and among farmers in Pennsylvania. They have the authority of Chaucer.

---

***Early instances in the wild of 'get shot of' and 'get shut of'***

Searches of Early English Books Online and of Google Books find one text from 1700 or earlier containing "got shot of" in the relevant sense and seventeen texts with one or more unique instances of "get/got shut of" in the same sense.

The instance of "got shot of" appears in a 1698 translation of Louis Hennepin, [*A New Discovery of a Vast Country in America Extending Above Four Thousand Miles Between New France and New Mexico*](https://books.google.com/books?id=F6ZJAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA160&dq=%22got+shot+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU74POjrb4AhWlAjQIHaN8AtwQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22got%20shot%20of%22&f=false):

> ...therefore he [Captain Michel] earnestly begged of him [the English admiral] to consider it, and not carry him to *Quebec*; that he should be more Serviceable to him, if he would permit him to go to the Three Rivers with Two Canou's laden with merchandize and provisions, to which place he would bring many of the Savages to trade with him. The Admiral relyed upon his Word and complyed with his desire: but the Man as soon as he **got shot of** the *English*, who had used him civilly enough for the good Service they expected from him, went clear away for the red Island; passed the River St. *Lawrence*, and so arrived at the River *Loup*; Since which the Admiral never heard more of him.

Instances of "get [or got] shut of" go back at least half a century earlier. From Francis Woodcock, [*The Two Witnesses: Discovered in Severall Sermons upon the Eleventh Chapter of the Revelation*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A96871.0001.001/1:4.4?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=got+shut+of) (1643):

> Is it not plain these plagues fall upon the Antichristian Party, when they are brought in at the tenth Verse, *rejoycing* for their slaughter, and this expresly the reason, Because they were now **got shut of** those, who while they lived, *tormented them with all these plagues*?
>
> ...
>
> But thus rather, *They rejoyce over them, because these two Witnesses tormented them*, meaning, That because these two Witnesses tormented them, when alive; therefore do they thus insult and triumph over them now, they are dead: or else thus; They rejoyce, because avenged, as also got rid of these Witnesses, and the reason why they rejoyce for this (as they conceive) so happy riddance, is, because these two Witnesses, while they were alive, grievously tormented them. This is then in short the meaning, The Popish faction rejoyce, because **got shut of** these Witnesses, fearing now no more to be tormented by them.

From James Parnell, [*The Watcher: or, The Stone Cut Out of the Mountains Without Hands, Striking at the Feet of the Image*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A91474.0001.001/1:6.1?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=got+shut+of) (1655):

> ... then I openly spoke to the people, that if any there could tax me, or lay any thing to my charge, I was there to answer, but none did or could there accuse me: so then I passed into the Castle-yard, then the wilde bruitish Schollars who had plotted together (as I was after informed) to abuse me, and they flocked together about me like the wilde beasts of the Forrest, & there I was tossed as amongst the raging waves of the Sea, to and fro, and at last was hurried into a house, where I **got shut of** those Caterpillars, which the Nation swarms with, but the baptised party passed away without disturbance, so it appears *the world loves its own*.

From James Naylor, [*An Answer to a Book called The Quakers Catechism, Put Out by Richard Baxter*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TrcAzdTyQ2gC&pg=PA28&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih3qj4k7b4AhWiIDQIHSwPBfg4ChDoAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1655):

> 19. *qu.* Is about singing *Davids* Psalms, and for answer to this thou sends us to a Book of *Cottons* and *Ford*, and say thou knows no reason why thou should add any more; a pretty shuffle to **get shut of** that thou canst not prove; yet though thou have lost thy reason to answer, thou wil ask more queres, 1. If the Scripture be written for our use, why may not we speak to God in *Davids* words?

From James Naylor (again), [*A Second Answer to Thomas Moore, to That Which He Calls, His Defence Against the Poyson, &c.*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A89851.0001.001/1:3?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=get+shut+of) (1656):

> I say, again, hath he [Christ] materiall flesh and bones, and not materiall blood, then is he not the same that he was, when he was upon earth. But why dost thou not make some answer to thy other clause; how people must do to **get shut of** their blood, seeing thy faith is, they cannot ascend till their blood be poured forth.

From Jonathan Johnson, "[The Quaker Quasht and his Quarrel Quelled](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A74963.0001.001/1:4?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=get+shut+of)" (1659):

> *Answ[er].* That is it thou strives for, to **get shut of** the Scriptures, for their witness torments thee, but thou labours in vain, for they will out-live all the generations of falshood, and be a continual witness against mens devices, as is plainly manifested in this.

From an [entry dated August 17–19, 1663](https://books.google.com/books?id=BjAJAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA239&dq=%22got+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1wfCej7b4AhXWBTQIHXUcCMsQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22got%20shut%20of%22&f=false) in the *Diary of Samuel Pepys*:

> Thence [from White Hall] homewards, taking leave of him [Mr. Moore], and met Tom Marsh, my old acquaintance at Westminster, who talks mightily of the honour of his place, being Clerke Assistant to the Clerke of the House of Commons, and I take him to be a coxcombe, and so did give him half a pint of wine, but drink none myself, and so **got shut of** him.

From a translation by R.L. of Francisco de Quevedo, [*The Visions of Dom Francisco de Quevedo Villegas, Knight of the Order of St. James*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Xx5EAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA141&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX2tqEkbb4AhUiAzQIHVpOBIkQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1667):

> But who are You, I pray'e? And what is your Business here? *My Poverty and These Rags*, quoth he, *are enough to tell ye that I am an honest man; a Friend to Truth, and one that will not be Mealy-Mouth'd, when he may speak it to Purpose*. Some call me the *Plain Dealer*; Others, the *Vndeceiver General*. You see me all in *Tatters, Wounds, Scars, Bruises*. And what is all This, but the *Requital* the *World* gives me, for my *Good Counsel*, and *Kind Visits*? And yet after all this endeavour to **get shut of** me; they call themselves my *Friends*: though they Curse me to the Pit of Hell, as soon as ever I come neer them; and had rather be hang'd, then spend one Quarter of an hour in my Company.

From Joseph Arrowsmith, [*The Reformation, a Comedy*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A25891.0001.001/1:8.2?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=get+shut+of) (1673):

> *Antonio.* But suppose that to your freedom I should offer that, which uses to be sweeter to your Sex, Revenge too?
>
> *Ismena.* Revenge would do something could I **get shut of** you once, but I swear you're grown so troublesome.

From Benjamin Stonham, [*Saul and David Compared Together, or, David's Picture Fully Drawn*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A61680.0001.001/1:3?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=get+shut+of) (1676):

> And notwithstanding that seeming Inward Authority and Command which some Professors are invested with, typified by *Sauls* Supremacy; yet are they sadly over powered by Satans temptations and their own corruptions still, which were Spiritually shadowed out by *Israels* Adversaries. Such may be made to think, that there is no way to **get shut of** Satan, but by their compliance with him in relation to some Lesser sins; which they could freely submit unto, but that they see at length, this will not satisfie their Adversary; as was the case of those men of *Jabesh*.

From Benjamin Stonham (again), [*The Parable of the Ten Virgin's Opened, or, Christ's Coming as a Bridegroom Cleared Up and Improved from Matthew XXV, ver. 1,2,3 &c.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ysNjAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA220&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX2tqEkbb4AhUiAzQIHVpOBIkQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1676):

> Nor will they be so weary (then) with Running in the way of Duty, nor faint with walking; but shall renew their strength, yea, seem to Mount up with wings as Eagles, *Isa.* 40. 31. Such will Abound with Service then, *Isa.* 66. 23. but yet without Complaining; the Labour of a Duty being then removed, when they shall **get shut of** Clogging Humours, and have a New Heart bestowed on them.

From an [untitled lead item](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rd5BAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA321&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih3qj4k7b4AhWiIDQIHSwPBfg4ChDoAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) in *The Observator* (April 18, 1683):

> But if you will have the short of the Story; the *Faction* of the *Two Houses* finding themselves *Countermin'd* by the *Army*; layd their heads together, *how* to **get *Shut* of** them by *Empeaching*, *Purging*, and *Disbanding*, &c.

From John Goodman, [*A Winter-Evening Conference Between Neighbours in Two Parts*](https://books.google.com/books?id=03tmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih3qj4k7b4AhWiIDQIHSwPBfg4ChDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1684):

> So that upon the whole matter, I see no tolerable account can be given of the way of drinking now in fashion; for it appears to have been taken up upon no necessity; it is recommended by no real advantage, either to the body or mind, and therefore must owe its rise to no better causes than dulness or idleness, a silly obsequiousness to other mens humours, or epicurism and wantonness of our own inclination. And for the habit of it, it is no better than a lewd artifice to avoid thinking, a way for a man to **get shut of** himself and of all sober considerations.

From Roger L'Estrange, [*A Brief History of the Times, &c.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BsYBSj9D__YC&pg=PA20&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX2tqEkbb4AhUiAzQIHVpOBIkQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1687–1688):

> The Faction were in a Fair way, by This time, to rid their Hands of the *King's Roman Catholique Friends*; and they were not without their *Expedients*, and *Inventions*, to **get shut of** *Reputed*, as well as of *Profess'd Papists*; For there needed but an *Impeachment*, an *Address*, a *Supposition*, or an *Opinion*, to the doing of the *Whole Work*.

From "[Jupiter and a Herds-man](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z_ZoAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA170&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX2tqEkbb4AhUiAzQIHVpOBIkQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false)," in *Fables of Æsop and Other Eminent Mythologists with Morals and Reflexions* (1692):

> Men should so Pray as not to Repent of their Prayers, and turn the most Christian and Necessary Office of our Lives into a Sin. We must not Pray in One Breath to *Find* a Thief, and in the Next to **get shut of** him.

From Adrien Baillet, [*The Life of Monsieur Des Cartes Containing the History of His Philosophy and Works*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A29412.0001.001/1:3?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=got+shut+of) (1693):

> But having examin'd every thing by the touchstone of Reason, he [Descartes] found at length that he could do nothing better than to continue in that Occupation which he then actually followed, since he had **got shut of** all the prejudices of his Education. This occupation did solely consist in imploying his whole Life to cultivate and improve his Reason, and to make the greatest progress he possibly could〈◊〉the knowledge of Truth, conformable to the method he had prescribed to himself.

From Martin Lister, [*A Journey to Paris in the Year 1698*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JjqbUDmIvTgC&pg=PA167&dq=%22get+shut+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiipIW5lrb4AhVmIzQIHUIFAvYQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22get%20shut%20of%22&f=false) (1699):

> Things that pass thus soon out of the Stomach, I suspect are little welcome there, and Nature makes haste to **get shut of** them. There are many things of this sort which impose upon us by procuring a false hunger.
>
> ...
>
> Another Argument, of the Dryness of the Air at *Paris*, we had from the alteration of Health; such as were thick Breathed, and Cought and Spit much, soon re∣covered; and the insensible perspiration of the Skin was so clear and free, that the Kidneys had little to do; so that it was observed by most, that though we drank pretty freely of the thin Wines of *Champagne* and *Burgundy*, yet they never broke our sleep to **get shut of** them; and that very little passed that way in the morning.

From "[Of the City-Mouse and Country-Mouse](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A26506.0001.001/1:5.1.9?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div3;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=got+shut+of)," in *Aesop's Fables English and Latin* (1700):

> When the servant was gone away, the City-Mouse comes again to the table, and invites the Country-Mouse. *He creeps out of his hole*, having scarcely **got shut of** his fear, at the last. He asks the City-Mouse *that invited him to drink*, whether this danger was often or no. He made answer, that it was every day, and ought to be slighted. Then quoth the Country-Mouse, Is it every day? *Truly thy dainties* have more bitter than sweet in them. Indeed I had rather have my want with security, than that abundance with such trouble of mind.

---

***Conclusions***

The history of "get shot of" and "get shut of" supports two conclusions: (1) the two expressions are almost certainly variants, not similar expressions with similar meanings; (2) "get shut of" was the earlier form of the expression and remained the more common form for a long time after "get shot of" began to appear.

Published instances of "get shut of" go back at least to 1643, whereas the earliest instance of get shot of" that I could find was from 1698; seventeen publications from 1700 and earlier included at least one unique occurrence of "get/got shut of," but only one such instance of "get/got shot of" did. Moreover "get shut of" begins to appear in bilingual dictionaries by 1679 and in English-only dictionaries by 1721, whereas the first dictionary occurrence of "get shot of" that I could find was from 1818.

Here is an Ngram chart of "get shot of" (blue line) vs. "got shot of" (red line) vs. "get shut of" (green line) vs. "got shut of" (yellow line) for the period 1700–2015:

[image: Image showing Google Ngram chart]

It shows that "get/got shut of" was more common than "get/got shot of" for hundreds of years and suggests that the latter surpassed the form in frequency only in the past 20 years or so. The rise in its popularity since about 1955 does not correlate with a consistent decline in the frequency of "get/got shut of," however.

Evidently, "get shut of" to mean "be rid of" arose in Britain (perhaps northern England) by the middle seventeenth century with a meaning akin to "put a shut door between oneself and the person or thing one wishes to be away from"—essentially the same meaning it has today. The emergence of "get/got shot of" some 50 years later may reflect nothing more than an orthographic/pronunciation difference in specific localities. The meaning seems to be identical for the "shut" form and the "shot" form.

Comment: I've made a few minor edits to your (excellent!) answer. Although, for the last sentence ("The meaning seem to be identical"), did you mean "The meaning`s` seem to be identical" or "The meaning seem`s` to be identical"?

Comment: @Justin: Thanks for correcting the various errors you spotted. The final sentence was a bit of a mess, so I've reworded it slightly. This was one of those answers where I had to reduce the character count to get the answer below the allowable maximum length, leading to some dubious last-minute decisions related to compressing the wording.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the max. character count, my bad.. If you need to make some more changes and you're out of characters, feel free to remove the image description (that I added). The line before the image explains it well anyway.

Comment: What an answer! I felt I had to choose an official answer quickly because two people had already marked my post as deserving of being closed. But thanks for this, really!

Comment: @PoundHash: The eagerness of some review queue reviewers to close great questions like yours is one of the most problematic aspects of this website. My guess is that the close voters felt either that you hadn't done enough research on your own (although you obviously did consult Collins) or that, since they couldn't readily and thoroughly answer the question themselves, it must call for an opinion-based answer. I'm glad that you found my answer useful; I enjoyed researching it and writing it.

Comment: @PoundHash Even if it does get closed, there are quite a few people on this site that love etymology and origin Qs...and would re-open the post in a heartbeat...

Comment: @PoundHash This site harbors several oft-contentious camps, and for some reason many of them  often find it more interesting to argue amongst  themselves about the merits and particulars of the question in comment, rather than address it  in a real answer. The current culture is stultifying. We need some type of reformation if the site will be judged successful going on into the future. We were recently  bought out by a another company, and if we don't show a profit, who knows?